# Como eu faço SEO?

Tags: html, seo

Eu comecei um blog faz pouco tempo, mas tempo o suficiente já pra ter visitas, 2 meses já, mas não tenho nenhuma! E já escrevi 10 artigos!
Me disseram que eu tinha que investir no SEO do site, a menos que eu quisesse pagar o Adwords.
Não entendo nada disso, mas não to a fim de gastar dinheiro por agora, até pq eu to quebrado....

O que é SEO? Como isso funciona? Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Sendo o advogado do diabo, um comment para complementar a resposta dada: SEO é uma coisa que acontece naturalmente quando você monta um site e faz a "lição de casa", que é organizar as informações, títulos, palavras chaves bem usadas, e texto objetivo. Depois, teve uma turma que inventou "ser especialista no assunto", o que me assusta um pouco, porque ser "profissional de SEO" é como ser um mecânico que só sabe mexer em freio dianteiro esquerdo de Kombi azul ano 1962. Então fica a sugestão: seja um bom blogueiro, estude SEO, escreva bem e organize suas páginas, que o melhor SEO é o conteúdo.

Comment: Vlw sr. Bacco, certificarei-me de seguir todas as suas dicas. Sou novo no assunto, mas quero fazer a coisa certa, até pq to sem dinheiro, kkk

Comment: com o tempo, vá pesquisando e se inteirando do assunto, mas sempre com o conteúdo em primeiro lugar. As técnicas são um complemento, que é bom você saber, mas elas estão ao alcance de qualquer bom profissional de web e os de marketing que estão em dia com o mercado.

Comment: Qualidade é muito mais importante do que quantidade. Não vai adiantar nada ficar postando diversos artigos em um curto período de tempo, o segredo está em você conseguir backlinks para o seu conteúdo (poste 1 artigo por mês e foque em trazer backlinks). Se quiser posso te recomendar o melhor curso de SEO na língua portguesa, abs!

Comment: Recomendação de curso tem grande chance de conseguir sinalização de Spam, além de não fazer parte do escopo do site. Sobre o mérito da qualidade, pois já tratei disso em comentários antigos nesta mesma questão. o Fato é que qualquer bom desenvolvedor web é melhor do que "especialista" em SEO, pois faz parte da profissão. Sobre o post (convertido em comment, com 2 sinalizações da comunidade), quando tiver 50 pontos vai poder deixar comentários em qualquer publicação, o campo de respostas é apenas para soluções de fato para a pergunta. A [help] pode dar uma noção melhor de como usar bem o site.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

SEO é a sigla para "Search Engine Optimization", que significa "otimização para mecanismos de busca", ou otimização de sites. SEO é o conjunto de estratégias com o objetivo de potencializar e melhorar o posicionamento de um site nas páginas 
de resultados naturais (orgânicos) nos sites de busca.

Em outras palavras, SEO é uma espécie de marketing técnico, é algo onde você depende não apenas da divulgação do site e da parte do marketing, como também deve seguir regrinhas básicas de lógica matemática impostas pelos algoritmos do Google e de outros sites de busca, para que seu site se destaque perante a concorrência, dentre elas está escolher as palavras-chave corretas para o seu artigo e o crescimento natural da quantidade de links apontando para o seu site, ao invés de fazer como muita gente que usa programas para criar links de divulgação e acaba se dando mal depois.

Vou te passar umas dicas que achei na internet, pra te ajudar a melhorar o SEO do seu site:

1. Personalize os Títulos das Suas Páginas
2. Crie Uma Logomarca Própria
3. Crie Títulos Personalizados no Google para Suas Páginas
4. Oculte as Páginas Desnecessárias
5. Coloque Nomes em Suas Imagens (Atributo ALT)
6. Escreva Conteúdo Inteligente e Original
7. Use Palavras-chave Específicas para cada Página
8. Cadastre-se nos Diretórios Locais
9. Utilize as redes sociais
10. Monitore Seu Progresso com Ferramenta de SEO
11. Use o Redirecionamento 301

Comment: Tou dando um +1 na sua por ser sucinto e objetivo, sem endeusar o SEO como se fosse uma ciência secreta.

Comment: Muito obrigado, amigo, tenho trabalhado tanto sem reconhecimento que não já sabia mais o que eram elogios, rs.

Comment: +1 boa resposta. Só nessa respostaa, já ganhou 4 'elogios'(votos).

Comment: Aliás, bem vindo ao SOpt! Não sei se já indicaram-te o [tour] para conhecer como a comunidade funciona. :D

Comment: Como criar uma logomarca própria pode ajudar?

Comment: Se o site for compatível com browsers mobile e for seguro (via https) também pode ajudar.

Answer (score -1):

Complementando as respostas dos colegas, você precisa otimizar sua página de maneira que os motores de busca possam encontra-la de acordo com seus parâmetros de busca, mas para isto deve ser levado em consideração:

1. Cada motor de busca possui seu algoritmo próprio, e este, sofre mudanças constantes. O google possui um algoritmo de SEO diferente do Yahoo por exemplo, e para atender ambos, você deve estuda-los e adequar sua página.
2. Cada algoritmo SEO tem seus parâmetros e regras específicas. Vale a pena estuda-los para obter melhor resultado. Exemplo: Em seu HTML, criar metatags para rotular/categorizar conteúdos e assuntos, usar palavras chaves, sinônimos e etc.
3. Ter em seu blog links para outros blogs famosos ou páginas com grande acesso também ajuda bastante, mas isto também deve ser feito da maneira correta.
4. Usar o google Adwords vale a pena! O google é o motor de busca mais utilizado (pelo menos no Brasil) e usar suas API´s lhe da uma boa vantagem. Para você ter ideia, o site da empresa que eu trabalhava tinha um SEO pobre ou quase inexistente e após contratar o Adwords, o volume de acesso à página cresceu absurdamente, pois ela era posicionada como primeira nas pesquisas por causa do Adwords.

Sugiro contratar um analista SEO para lhe prestar consultoria por algumas horas (eles cobram por hora geralmente) e dar uma organizada em seu blog. Assim vc o otimiza para SEO e acompanhando o trabalho, pega uma boa noção.

Sugiro também pagar o Adwords pelo menos no início para você ter uma divulgação inicial e depois, manter.

O trabalho de SEO é constante, precisa ser otimizado sempre. Se você quer estar sempre nos primeiros lugares acostume-se com a ideia. E caso não consiga, não desanime! Existem empresas especializadas que ficam 24h por conta disso e ainda não conseguem ficar na primeira página de resultados do google.

Dependendo do seu caso, fique feliz por aparecer na terceira ou quarta página. Já o Adwords, pode te colocar na primeira, lembre-se disso!

Comment: Acho que contratar um analista SEO para ele é inviável no momento. A ideia aqui é justamente aprender a fazer sem investir muito (ou nenhum) dinheiro.

Comment: Analista SEO geralmente é um cara que cobra pra fazer o que um bom desenvolvedor de conteúdo web já faz como parte do serviço. É como mandar um carro no mecânico e ter que pagar um cara separado para trocar a mola da suspensão traseira esquerda. É engraçado como o povo gosta de ser enganado no Brasil.