# Search engine optimization em Meta Tags (Custom Elements)

Tags: seo, angular, react, vue.js

Como funciona a indexação de meta tags criada em frameworks como vue.js e outros que usam dessa funcionalidade ?

Os robôs do Google analisam o que o browser interpreta ou o source code da pagina ?

Comment: Analisam o source, resultado gerado dinâmicamente não é analisado

Comment: Existe maneiras de não perder indexação por usar desses elementos ?

Comment: Sobre o Vue.js eu encontrei isso: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html#SEO

Comment: Olá.
Sugiro dar uma lida nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103585/33611

Comment: Nao sei como funciona nas outras tecnologias, mas com angular se utiliza uma tecnica chamada server-side rendering para se fazer o seo.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como eu faço SEO?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103563/como-eu-fa%c3%a7o-seo)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O google leva mais em consideração o nome de View/Controller ou Parametros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266584/o-google-leva-mais-em-considera%c3%a7%c3%a3o-o-nome-de-view-controller-ou-parametros)

Answer (score -2):

Bem legal a pergunta. Eu tenho trabalhado com Javascript frameworks e realmente vejo essa pergunta com frequencia. Os bots estao evoluindo constantemente. Existem varios, nao soh do google, mas tambem de outros mecanismos de busca e outros indexadores. O do Google eh o mais avancado e ele acaba *sim* lendo o javascript. Mas os demais *nao* leem os arquivos *.js* e somente os arquivos *html*. Isso significa que se voce nao renderizar no servidor as paginas de uma SPA ou framework JS voce nao tera uma boa indexacao no geral entre os mecanismos de busca (SEO).