# O google leva mais em consideração o nome de View/Controller ou Parametros?

Tags: seo

Estou com essa duvida pois estou tentando subir o meu site no rank, e até o momento ele não aparece em `banco de imagens`, ai veio a duvida, o google entende o que é um parâmetro e o que é uma view/controller?

Utilizo ASP.NET MVC, atualmente preciso criar uma nova página para chamar atenção com a tag `banco de imagens`, e para isso pensei em criar algo do tipo:

site.com.br/banco-de-imagens

ou

site.com.br/BancoDeImagens

Onde a primeira opção é um parâmetro(com url amigável) e a segunda é um novo Controller no meu MVC.

Qual o google leva mais em consideração ?

Comment: Faça um teste A/B com os domínios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Google Bot não vê nenhuma diferença.

Ele solicitará a página e obterá o código HTML gerado de volta, por isso não se importa se é uma página estática ou uma página *gerada*. Ele nunca verá o código do servidor, apenas o resultado da execução do código no Browser.

Nem sequer é possível dizer a diferença com certeza quando você solicita uma página. Muitas páginas geradas têm uma extensão de arquivo diferente que páginas estáticas (por exemplo, .aspx ou .php em vez de .html), *mas as páginas geradas também podem ser imprimidas com a mesma extensão de arquivo de página estática.*

> OBS: Faz um **teste A/B**, crie as duas páginas e use uma Canonical Tag. Na página de teste coloca `<link rel="canonical" href="https://URLoficial.com.br" />` *(isso vai dizer ao Google que o conteúdo da página B é o mesmo da "https://URLoficial.com.br")* Depois avalia no Analytics a URL que está dando mais resultado.

Referência no Google sobre **conteúdo duplicado**: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=pt-BR

Documentação do Google para fazer um teste **A/B** https://support.google.com/360suite/optimize/answer/6211930?hl=pt-BR

Answer (score 3):

Ninguém sabe ao certo como o algoritmo do Google verifica os domínios e propriedades para rankear cada uma, mas é claro que não é baseado em uma e outra técnica. Sabe-se também que o Google preza muito pela experiencia do usuário ao acessar alguma coisa, desde velocidade até legibilidade, enfim, a usabilidade como um todo, sendo assim penso o seguinte, talvez não seja a resposta correta (mas como ninguém conhece o algoritmo do Google não pode dizer estar errada), mas pra mim segue a essa lógica.

Se você seguir alguns parâmetros e testar alguns pontos em cada questão, poderá chegar a uma solução favorável em todos os sentidos.
Então pense:

- Qual dos links seria mais interessante/fácil para o usuário
  escrever/decorar/acessar
- Veja se existe uma diferença significativa de desempenho entre os
  dois métodos.

Se existirem, compare outros pontos relativos a outras métricas também. E lembre, não adianta ter um link bonitinho e ele ser uma carroça puxada por um burro manco, maximize todos pontos possíveis sempre.